# ClientDataSet(random record) last record play- error "At beginning of table"

Tags: delphi

An error occurred while playing the last record in the table - **At beginning of table**  How to fix it.

```
procedure TForm1.btnNextClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  self.ListBox1.ItemIndex := Random(ListBox1.Items.Count) - 0 ;
  AddALL();
  begin
   ClientDataSet1.RecNo:=Random(ClientDataSet1.RecordCount) - 0;
   PlayFile(self.exePath + '\' + self.ClientDataSet1.FieldByName('mp3').AsString, MediaPlayer1,Image2);
   end
end;
```

Comment: And how are readers supposed to know what `AddALL()` does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Val Marinov* seems to have given you a good answer to your question.
I just want to add
some points that don't directly answer your question but may help you avoid making some mistakes.

You have some code

```
self.ListBox1.ItemIndex := Random(ListBox1.Items.Count)
```

which you want to use to set the listbox's `ItemIndex` to a random, valid value.  There are a couple of things which are asking for trouble about this:

**1. Wrong way to use `Random`**

The [online help for the `Random` function](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.Random) says

> In Delphi code, **Random** returns a random number within the range 0 <= X < Range. If Range is not specified, the result is a real-type random number within the range
>
> ```
> 0 <= X < 1.
> ```

For a ListBox, the range of valid ItemIndex values is `0..Items.Count - 1`.  But `Random` can return a fractional part, so a better way to write what you want is:

```
ListBox1.ItemIndex := Trunc(Random(ListBox1.Items.Count));
```

Called like that, `Random` will return a value below `ListBox1.Items.Count`, and the call to `Trunc` discards the fractional part.

**2.  Unnecessary use of `self`.**

Your code is liberally sprinkled with the `self` qualifier. Having to use `self` like that is usually a sign of bad or sloppy coding.
In your `TForm1.AddALL`, the `self` in the first line tells the compiler that the instance of `ListBox1` you are referring to is the one which is the `TListBox` component on your `TForm1`, rather than some other `ListBox1` variable which may also be in scope (e.g. a global variable called `ListBox1`) when the line is compiled. But the way to avoid that problem is to avoid having the other `ListBox1` in scope in the first place.
I suggest you simply delete all the instances of `self.`, because you shouldn't need to have them.

**3. Avoid setting dataset RecordNumber**

Finally, don't get into the habit of relying on the fact that `TClientDataSet` allows you to specify a value for `RecordNumber`, it is rarely a good idea and few dataset types support it.
If you want to go to a random record, better use

```
Dataset.First;
DataSet.MoveBy(Random(X));
```

I leave it to you to work out what the argument `X` to `Random` should be, to move to a valid, random, record, based on what the online help says about `Random`.

Comment: ClientDataSet1.MoveBy(Random(ClientDataSet1.RecordCount));

Answer (score 0):

> Record Numbers
>
> Client datasets support a second way of moving directly to a given
>   record in the dataset: setting the RecNo property of the dataset.
>   RecNo is a one-based number indicating the sequential number of the
>   current record relative to the beginning of the dataset.
>
> You can read the RecNo property to determine the current absolute
>   record number, and write the RecNo property to set the current record.
>   There are two important things to keep in mind with respect to RecNo:
>
> **Attempting to set RecNo to a number less than one, or to a number greater than the number of records in the dataset results in an At
>   beginning of table, or an At end of table exception, respectively.**
>
> The record number of any given record is not guaranteed to be constant. For instance, changing the active index on a dataset alters
>   the record number of all records in the dataset.
>
> NOTE
>
> **You can determine the number of records in the dataset by inspecting
>   the dataset's RecordCount property. When setting RecNo, never attempt
>   to set it to a number higher than RecordCount.**

See : http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/DB_TDataSet_RecNo.html

Comment: May be `RandomRange(1,ClientDataSet1.RecordCount);` (Add `Math` in uses clause.) This way you will avoid '0', which I guess is causing you a problem. http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=RandomRange&ExpandCode1=Yes

Comment: `ClientDataSet1.RecNo := Random(ClientDataSet1.RecordCount) + 1`  works because of when Random return 0 then value is 1. But when Random return RecordCount then error will raised because value will be RecordCount + 1